# Python - Updating JSON objects in a file

Tags: python, json

I have a (valid) JSON file contaning JSON objects, each object taking up one file line.  These JSON objects map to Python dicts, and are in ascending order by numerical IDs.

I am writing an update method that accepts three arguments: (1) a file path, (2) a list of ordered IDs, and (3) a dict of JSON object properties with update values, and goes through the file (opened in `r+` mode), looking for the JSON objects in the ID list, and then updates the object properties using the values in the dict, and writes the object back to file.

Each object takes up a line, and is comma separated.  If the desired ID is in a line then before writing to the file the pointer is moved back by the length of the line to the beginning.  But the problem is the new object line may be longer, in that case it is overwriting the line of another object following that object.

I just need to replace the line that I'm interested in, but not overwrite subsequent lines.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
def update_JSON_file( self, file_path, obj_IDs, obj_props ):

    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()

    with io.open( file_path, 'r+', encoding='utf=8' ) as file:
        IDs_iter = iter( obj_IDs )
        for line in file:
            ID = IDs_iter.next()
            if str( ID ) in line:
                JSON_obj = decoder.raw_decode( line )[0]
                for key in props.keys():
                    JSON_obj[key] = props[key] 
                JSON_obj = json.dumps( JSON_obj, ensure_ascii=False )
                if '},\n' in line: JSON_obj += ',\n'
                JSON_obj = unicode( JSON_obj )
                file.seek( file.tell() - len( line ) )
                file.write( JSON_obj )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want, because you can only surgically replace *fixed length records* in a file. You cannot replace the line with something that is longer or shorter, as files don't store data as separate lines.

In addition, your code doesn't take into account that on some platforms (like on Windows) lines in text files are separated by two characters, representable in Python as `\r\n`, but these line endings are translated for you to the single character `\n`. Your line length calculation doesn't take that into account.

You instead have to rewrite **everything** following that line. You'd be better of using a database; `sqlite3` comes bundled with Python, take a look at that.

Comment: My plan is to use SQLite3 obviously, because I want this to be in a relational db, but I just wondered whether there was any way of doing this via JSON only.  THanks.

Comment: @ramius: you could, but only if you padded objects to a fixed length so you can treat each entry as a record. Longer objects would have to be cut up to fit into multiple records, shorter objects need to have some form of padding added to make up the extra characters. Then you can seek back and forth at your heart's content.

Comment: @ramius: but SQLite has that all already worked out (the file format it uses almost certainly deals in a fixed records) so why have that dog but then bark yourself?

Answer (score 0):

```
def update_JSON_file( self, file_path, obj_IDs, props ):
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    with io.open( file_path, 'r+', encoding='utf=8' ) as files:
        IDs_iter = iter( obj_IDs )
        fl = files.read().splitlines(True)
        ID = IDs_iter.next()
        for i,line in enumerate(fl):
            # ID = IDs_iter.next()
            # I think the 'ID' should be initialized out of the loop
            # and iterated only if the condition is true
            if str(ID) in line:
                JSON_obj = decoder.raw_decode(line)[0]
                for key in props.keys():
                    JSON_obj[key] = props[key] 
                JSON_obj = json.dumps( JSON_obj, ensure_ascii=False )
                if '},\n' in line: JSON_obj += ',\n'
                JSON_obj = unicode( JSON_obj )
                fl[i] = JSON_obj
                try:
                    ID = IDs_iter.next()
                except StopIteration:
                    break
        files.seek(0)
        files.write(''.join(fl))
        return True
```