# Most Logical Way (in Python) to Edit JSON file on disk

Tags: python, json

What is the most logical way to read through a JSON file (where each JSON object is separated by a \n) and change one of the values?

Let's pretend that I have 5 million JSON objects where one of the fields is "apple" but needs to be "orange" instead. Keep in mind I've fixed the source code that generates this data (so this will never happen again) but the job takes about 2 weeks to run so I'd rather just patch this as opposed to running the job again and waiting 2 weeks.

I'm a novice programmer but I'm thinking the best way to do this is:

1. read through the original file one line at a time
2. for each line in file:
3. load the data via json.loads(line) to a variable called json_data
4. change apple to orange in json_data
5. Write json_data to a new file
6. Write a newline character
7. repeat until end of the apple file is reached

Is there an easy way to do this in place or am I better off using 2 files?

Many thanks

Comment: I think your solution using two files is straightforward and ideal.

Comment: how big is your file in GBs?

Comment: All of the files that need editing are only around 1GB thankfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In-place edits" of **text** files, in practice, are always done by reading the input file, writing the output one, and switching them atomically when done.  That's because a file is a compact array of bytes: changes usually alter some logical field's length, which would require shifting all following bytes up, or down -- impractical, much better to read-and-rewrite everything that's not changed!

In Python, the `stdlib` module `fileinput` is the one to hide this reality (to some extent) under an elegant wrapper.  I.e:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('thefile.name', inplace=True):
    line = transform(line)
    print line,
```

(in Python 2 -- `print(line,end='')` in Python 3, equivalently).

You only need to define the line-by-line transform function and you're all set!  E.g,

```
def transform(line):
    return line.replace('"apple"', '"orange"')
```

would be the equivalent of the `sed` solution proposed in one answer.  But, you can apply much-deeper logic, including `json.loads`, transformations of the resulting structure, and `json.dumps` it back again, as and if necessary...!

Comment: Thank you Alex, I really appreciate your thoughtful answer! I'm following your logic but have one question: you're making call to print line but I would ultimately need to make a call to json.dump(line, file). This begs the question then - what file would I be passing to  json.dumps()? The original file or a new file? Specifically, like the first part of your post, I'm trying to comprehend the "changes usually alter some logical field's length" statement. This is also referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516751/python-updating-json-objects-in-a-file?rq=1

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to understand is when you say it is "much better to read-and-rewrite everything that's not changed!", where are you rewriting to? Also, since every JSON object is messed up, there won't be a single record not changed in this case

Comment: Okay I've wrote my transform function but it always leaves my source file blank. Any suggestions? I'm not using the print statement, if that makes any difference.

Comment: The `print` within the `for line in fileinput.input` loop is exactly what emits data to the replacement file.  So yes it **does** make a **HUGE** difference -- no `print`, blank replacement file.  Use `json.dumps` to make a **string**, return that string from `transform`, use the `print` of that in the loop, exactly as I showed -- **no** `json.dump` to any **file** in this approach!-)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a Python solution, but what about doing this in shell:

```
sed -i 's/"apple"/"orange"/g' your_file.txt
```

Note that this will change all fields `"apple"` to `"orange"` in your whole file. But adding the double quotes (`"`) at least ensures that only fields containing only `apple` will be replaced, not just the word `apple` found somewhere in another random field.

Of course, you should backup your original file before proceeding.

Comment: This might create horrible side effects when there is `apple` in another field.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that uspowpow as newcomer to programming knows that this can do hard to discover unwanted changes to his expensively gathered data.

Comment: Thanks Jivan! I unfortunately can only use your method when I know that the output will always be orange (and 50% of the time I need to process the input in order to determine whether it needs to be orange or watermelon for example). However, I definitely need to learn some UNIX-fu and your answer just taught me something very useful about sed and for that I thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your file will fit in Memory, just load it and edit it. It would be faster than sequentially reading, loading and writing one object at a time.
e.g.

```
>>> data=open(fpath).read()
>>> data = json.loads(data)
>>> data['xxx']='yyy'
>>> fw=open(fpath,'w')
>>> json.dump(data, fw)
```

Comment: so.... something like.... 
    file = open('json_file', 'r')
    for line in file:
        make_the_change()
    file.close()

Comment: @uspowpow yes just open it modify it and dump it out